# Trying to display multiple rows of data when a certain month is selected if the month matches the specific month

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

When I click on a certain month e.g January. It should then display all data from the database from the month January. The same for every other month. I am using PHP, JavaScript, HTML and CSS to do this. I orginally had one way working, however it would only display 1 piece of data specific to that month, when changed to a class element, it stopped working. Currently, nothing is displayed, no error returns when a month is clicked on either.

The PHP:

```
if($row['month'] === 'January'){

                echo '<div class="rallyPrintJanuary">';
                echo "<h2>" . $row['rallyVenue'] . " in " . $row['month'] . " " . $row['year'] . "</h2>";
                echo "<h4>Event: ". $row['rallyEvent'] . " </h4>";
                echo "<h3>Your Marshall(s): " . $row['rallyMarsh'] . "</h3>";
                echo "<h4>When? ". $row['rallyDate'] . " </h4>";
                echo "<p>" . $row['rallyDesc'] . "</p>";
                echo "<p>How much? ". $row['rallyCost'] . " </p>";
                echo "<p>How long? ". $row['rallyNights'] . " Nights</p>";
                echo "<p>Pitch Limit? ". $row['pitchLimit'] . "</p>";
                echo "<p>Phone Number: 0". $row['phoneNo'] . " </p>";
                echo "<p>Email: <a href='mailto:". $row['email'] . "'> ". $row['email'] ."</a></p>";
                echo "<p>Please make sure you to contact ". $row['rallyMarsh'] . " for more information.</p>";
                if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
                    echo "<a href='' id='". $row['rallyId'] . "' class='trash'>Delete</a>";
                }
                echo "</div><br>";
                 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="calander-container">
        <div class="months">
            January
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            February
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            March
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            April
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            May
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            June
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            July
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            August
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            September
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            October
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            November
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            December
        </div>
    </div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            let monthArray = document.querySelectorAll(".months");

        monthArray.forEach(function(monthh){
            monthh.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
                    const monthName = document.getElementsByClassName("months").textContent;
                    const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
                    months.forEach(month => {

                        const el = document.getElementsByClassName('rallyPrint' + month);

                        if (monthName === month) {

                                el[0].style.display = "block"; // Show current month

                        }else if(!month){
                            el[0].style.display = "none"; //Not the current month, hide
                        }   


                   });
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a database? The $row[] function selects a single row from a table. So you would need a database. Also when you do `if($row['month'] === 'January')` that's like saying `if(table Month === January) {}` You can't really say if **Table** equal to this thing, e.g. January do this a table isn't really equal to anything, maybe something in the table but not the table itself. Oh, also you spelled month wrong in your JS might wanna fix that. Last but not least another reason your thing might not be printing is because you did this `echo "<h2>" . $row['rallyVenue'] . " in " . $row['month'] . " " . $row['year'] . "</h2>";` I think to print a line like that you might like something like this  `echo '<p class="UserPost">' . $row["MainPagePosts"] . " | Posted By: " . $row["PostUser"] . "</p>";`